# Add autoincrement field in a table

Tags: mysql

I need you save my live. 
I have a table with a LOT of rows. One of the fields are id, it have auto_increment.

For legally reasons, now I need to have another auto increment field (not auto_numeric, I will be control this manually). It fields in the firs row starts at 567.

How I can add i exists rows the new correlative number?  568 ,569, 570...

Comment: I'm not totally certain about what you're looking for, but I'd loop the records via PHP and set the field manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

SET @pos =566;
UPDATE mytable SET field_id2 = ( SELECT @pos := @pos +1 ) ORDER BY id ASC;

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure and use a [CURSOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) to achieve what you want, using a cursor you can iterate the results of a query and perform certain operations(in your case an [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement) on each row that’s returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new int field and then update it with

```
UPDATE table SET new_column = auto_increment_column + 567;
```

Of course, that will also keep all the breaks in the original column. You can drop the `auto_increment` field and re-add it to eliminate it. It'll take a few hours, but a life's worth it, I guess.

If you really need to manually renumber the fields, you'll probably just have to go the way the previous commenters have suggested and use either PHP or cursors to loop through all the records.